# Picard group of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

I suppose the Picard group of a complete curve $C$ in $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $d>2$ is complicated. So, if we remove a general point $x\in C$ and denote $C'=C-x$, I think we have $\mathcal O_{C'}(1)\neq \mathcal O_{C'}$, here $\mathcal O_{C'}(1)$ is the restriction of $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^n$ to $C'$. I would like to know if the following is true:

> Let $C_\lambda$ be a family of degree $d~(d>2)$ curves in $\mathbb P^n$ covering $\mathbb P^n$ and passing through some common $x$, and let $C_\lambda'=C_\lambda-x$. Is it true that there is at least one $\lambda$ such that $\mathcal O_{C_\lambda'}(1)\neq \mathcal O_{C_\lambda'}$?

Any comment or reference would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This may not be true in general. As an example take $n=2$, $x=(1,0,0)$ and the family of all quadrics of the form $ay^2+byz+cz^2=0$.

Comment: @Mohan I think the quadratic case is also too special and should be excluded. I edited the setting to be $d>2$.

Comment: Do you think the restriction of $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^n$ to $C'$ is well-defined ?

Comment: If all curves are smooth and rational, this is not true.

Comment: @Mohan I think it can never be rational since degree is at least 3.

Comment: @reuns I think it is. One has the immersion morphism hence it induces the pullback map on Picard groups.

Comment: When $n \ge 3$ there are smooth rational curves in $\mathbb{P}^n$ of any degree.